# Python class not in globals when using decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

Maybe the title is a bit misleading, however I wanted to create a simple decorator to decorate some class methods as "allowed" in an RPC mechanism, but I'm stuck on a strange error when trying to access class variables (Python 2.7.5). Check the code below:

```python
class myclass():

    rpcallowedmethods = []

    def __init__(self):            
        pass

    def rpcenabled(fn):
        print fn
        print globals()
        print myclass

    @rpcenabled
    def somefunc(self,param):
        pass

c = myclass()
```

Exception: `NameError: global name 'myclass' is not defined`

Anyone can explain the reason behind this to me?

EDIT:
What I'm asking is more about the fact that python executes the decorator defined in a class and run against decorated classmethods even prior having the class in the globals, so I believed it's more of a logical "bug" in the python implementation than a seemingly obvious NameError

Comment: The `rpcenabled` decorator makes no sense. First of all, it should not be defined _inside_ of your class, second of all, the `NameError` comes from the print statement _within_ the `rpcenabled` call as `myclass` is not yet defined when the decorator is executed (which is during _creation_ of the class object - your class is being compiled and does not yet exist). Your `print globals()` should have showed you this. What do you actually want the decorator to do?

Comment: I was not aware that python have such a selective parser, since it was already in the definition of the class I thought it must have parsed it prior executing any decorated methods...

Comment: Well, the parser basically works like this when creating classes: it creates an empty class object, takes all the code belonging to the class definition, fills the class object by executing all class-level statements (creating functions, executing function decorators, assigning class variables), passes the filled class object to any class decorators, and _then_ assigns the result to the name of the class in the surronding scope. This assignment is the very last step in the process. In your specific case, just pass your `rpcallowedmethods` list to the decorator instead of using the class.

Comment: Martino Dino, it would be a logical "bug" if the class were to exist in `globals()` _before_ it was finished being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual class object is only assigned to its name *after* its definition is finished. Thus you cannot use the class name during its definition. You can either create a decorator outside of the class to which you explicitly pass the list you want to fill, or use the following:

```
class myclass():
    rpcmethods = []

    def _rpcallowed(fct, l=rpcmethods):
        l.append(fct)
        return fct

    @_rpcallowed
    def myfct(): pass
```

Note that the default parameter (`l=rpcmethods`) is a workaround as you cannot access a class variable inside of a function without a reference to the class or an instance.

The variant with the decorator *outside* of the class would probably qualify as being "cleaner" than this as it's explicit and reusable, but it would be a bit more code and less specific.

Comment: That worked great, after some testing with complete implementation of a few classes this turns to be the cleanest and simplest solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're abusing decorators. A decorator is meant to add something to thing object is given. "decorating" it somehow.

The more usual way to do something like this would be to decorate both the method and the class. Metaclasses are another way to solve this problem. They're more powerful, but are overkill for your current problem. However, directly decorating the functions might be all you need to do. And save collating the rpc functions for when a proxy is made.

```
from types import FunctionType

def enable_rpc(func):
    func.rpc_enabled = True
    return func

def rpc_enabled_class(cls):
    functions = [attr for attr in vars(cls).values() 
        if isinstance(attr, FunctionType)]
    cls._rpc_enabled_methods = [
        func for func in functions
            if getattr(func, "rpc_enabled", False)
    ]
    return cls

@rpc_enabled_class
class SampleClass(object):

    @enable_rpc
    def my_func(self):
        pass

print(SampleClass._rpc_enabled_methods)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange error?

```
print myclass
```

caused the error. You can't use the name `myclass` in its definition...

Comment: The print was added to demonstrate the issue, in reality the code was more like `myclass.rpcallowedmethods.append(fn.__name__)`

Comment: @MartinoDino If you want to use the class, defined a `@classmethod` and its first argument is `cls` which is the class.